# define two intent in An Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, intentfilter

I need to start an Activity with two different Intent, can I define two Intents In an Activity node?

An real example is: in my **current** application, I want to start an **main Activity** in another android application, how can I implement such requirement?

can I add another **Intent-Filter** in the following **Activity** Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. An activity can have several intent filters.